# array php to javascript with chrome

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome

In chrome, I have the following problem. (I don't have the problem in firefox.)

Here is my code:

```
echo $name[0]; // outputs: apple
```

and I use in Javascript:

```
var name= <?php echo json_encode($name ); ?>;
document.write(name[0] + "<br>");  // outputs: a
```

I want the `name[0]` showing `apple` but not `a`. How can I fix it?

Comment: Which data type is `$name` ? Can you show the output of `var_dump($name)` ?

Comment: The data type in database is varchar. Here is the code I get the name. $name[]=mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT Name FROM table WHERE ID = '".$id[$x]."';"),"0")
var_dump($name[0])
output: string 'apple' (length=5)

Comment: I use another method to do the answer:
var browser = navigator.vendor;
if(browser == 'Google Inc.'){
...
var newname = name.split(",");
}else{...}

Answer (score 0):

I've written what you've described here:

```
<?php
$name = ['apple', 'banana', 'pear'];
?>
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          var array = <?php echo json_encode($name);?>;
          document.write(array[0]+'<br>');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And `apple`is written in the document body as you wanted. Now this only happens if your array (variable `$name`) actually has an array with `"apple"` as the first element.

You might be getting the error you've described if `$name` contains `"apple"` (a string) , in which case PHP   tries to acces the first letter in `"apple"`.